# Present Continuous vs Present Perfect Continuous vs Present Simple (Time periods)

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous, progressive-aspect

Are all the three correct and is there a difference?

- Normally, I don't work much but I work a lot this week.
- Normally, I don't work much but I am working a lot this week.
- Normally, I don't work much but I have been working a lot this week.

Can we use present continuous to speak about this week, this month, this year? How about using them with words **lately**, **recently**, and **now**?

More Examples:

- I am taking an exam next Monday so I study hard this week.
- I am taking an exam next Monday so I am studying hard this week.
- I am taking an exam next Monday so I have been studying hard this week.

Comment: Yes we can.  There is no temporal restriction whatsoever on the use . You will be wishing you had set some food aside, come winter, Mr Grasshopper.

Comment: I've upvoted Tromano's comment because I agree that both are fine, but realize that if we are speaking in context, one may be more appropriate than the other (and perhaps, even wrong).

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence in each of your examples is grammatically incorrect. The other two sentences in both examples are fine.

'Now' is okay to use with the Present Continuous - *I am answering your question now.*

'Recently' and 'lately' need the Present Perfect - *I have been answering/I have answered a lot of questions recently/lately.*